# retrieving and assigning corresponding with and height and with of images in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing an slideshow application. So I have a checkboxes with the corresponding images. So when the user selects the checkboxes and click continue button, the corresponding images should be retrieved by javascript and set its height and width. If height/width is not specified for a particular image, it will be filled with height="" else it will be filled width the height=valuepx. how do I achieve do this.. I could get the array of images but how do I retrieve the same for height and width of corresponding images. Please help... I am a beginner to JS..

```
function insert_slide()

{ var height;
```

var width;

```
var img=new Array();
var count=0;
var names=document.getElementsByName('image_id');//name of checkboxes


for(i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
if(names[i].checked)
    {count=count+1;

    img[i] = "<IMG SRC='" + names[i].value + "'";


    if(height != '') {
        img[i] += " height='" + height[i] + "'";

        }

    else{
    img[i] += " height='"+""+  "'"; 
        }
    if(width != '') {
        img[i] += " width='" + width[i] + "'"; 
    }
else{
img[i] += " width='"+""+  "'"; 
}

}


}



}
```

Comment: You are comparing against `height` and `width` but you never define these values anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared width/height so their values are undefined.
What do you want to do with width and height and what are their values ?

Comment: The height and width values are dynamically loaded.. so we cannot hardcode it.. If I pass an array of these height and width values through my serverside programming(like function insert_slide()
heightarray, widtharray))then does it make sense..??

Comment: Basically I need to assign the corresponding image's height and width to img[i].

Comment: You can know image size by creating an Image object. But I don't understand why do you want to force width/height image in html...

Comment: I am trying to retrieve these images url's which are selected and then will check whether the image has dimensions defined. If not we will assign it as "". Else it will be given that value thru javascript.

Comment: Can you post your entire code in a jsfiddle for more understanding please ?